# To receive a boot complete intent in ICS?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, boot

I am having a broadcast receiver that starts a service in ICS. I have not activity associated with the code. The issue that I am facing is that I am unable to receive the BOOT COMPLETED broadcast in my receiver. Is there a round about solution for this?

Comment: show us how you do it and we will tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: We are not here to to do your job while you get paid in full.Please show us what you've tried from alex's answer and we can go ahead then

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Android, an application must have been manually started by the user at least once before any background stuff can be run, so you're going to need an Activity.